# Usage of filters

Tags: filters

Why is the filter removed after fetching feeds in the following example (from WordPress.org?)

```
<?php
function return_7200( $seconds )
{
  // change the default feed cache recreation period to 2 hours
  return 7200;
}

add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_7200' );
$feed = fetch_feed( $feed_url );
remove_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_7200' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is added before the call to `fetch_feed`, then immediately removed so only that particular feed is given a different feed cache transient lifetime. Any other `fetch_feed` calls within the lifetime of the request won't have that filter applied, so will be given whatever the default cache transient lifetime value is.